# Errors when fetching sys cursor from plsql using jdbc

Tags: java, stored-procedures, jdbc, plsql, oracle10g

I have a stored procedure which returns sys_refcursor and I am trying to fetch the cursor from java using JDBC.

plsql stored procedure

```
 create or replace procedure my_proc(p_deptno IN number,p_emp_no IN varchar2
    , p_cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
    is
    begin
    open p_cursor FOR
    select *
    from emp
    where deptno = p_deptno and emp_number=p_emp_no;
    end proc;
    /
```

java code

```
callablestatement = connection.prepareCall("{cal my_proc(?,?,?)} ");
callablestatement.setInt(1, param1);
callablestatement.setString(2, param2);
callablestatement.registerOutParameter(3, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
callablestatement.execute();
resultSet = ((OracleCallableStatement)callablestatement).getCursor(4);
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                <classname> = mapList(resultSet);
                logger.info(resultSet.getString(1));
            }
```

When I execute the above I am getting the following execeptions

```
java.lang.NullPointerException at callablestatement.execute();
```

and

```
Non supported SQL92 token at position: 3: cal
```

Comment: at  `callablestatement.execute();` Thanks

Comment: Take a look at the `prepareCall` line.  Should that be `call my_proc` instead of `cal my_proc`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue by using a function with the same code as in the procedure and it has resolved my issue.

And I called my function using the following manner.

```
private final String FUNCTIONAME= "begin ? :=myfunc(?,?,?); end;"";
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your statement:

```
{cal my_proc(?,?,?)}
```

should be

```
{call my_proc(?,?,?)}
```

Comment: It was a typo when I copied here in stackoverflow.com. Thanks

Comment: @Polappan Are you sure? Because that typo is also included in the error message in your question.

Answer (score 0):

use `theCallableStatement.setObject(`  instead 
Of

`.setString` and `.setInt` etc

it has also `theCallableStatement.setNull` for null

but keep `registerOutParameter` the same

**description for the method**

> Sets the value of the designated parameter with the given object. The
>   second parameter must be of type Object; therefore, the java.lang
>   equivalent objects should be used for built-in types. The JDBC
>   specification specifies a standard mapping from Java Object types to
>   SQL types. The given argument will be converted to the corresponding
>   SQL type before being sent to the database. Note that this method may
>   be used to pass datatabase- specific abstract data types, by using a
>   driver-specific Java type. If the object is of a class implementing
>   the interface SQLData, the JDBC driver should call the method
>   SQLData.writeSQL to write it to the SQL data stream. If, on the other
>   hand, the object is of a class implementing Ref, Blob, Clob, NClob,
>   Struct, java.net.URL, or Array, the driver should pass it to the
>   database as a value of the corresponding SQL type. This method throws
>   an exception if there is an ambiguity, for example, if the object is
>   of a class implementing more than one of the interfaces named above.
>   Note: Not all databases allow for a non-typed Null to be sent to the
>   backend. For maximum portability, the setNull or the setObject(String
>   parameterName, Object x, int sqlType) method should be used instead of
>   setObject(String parameterName, Object x).

Comment: -1 without comment how could i learn to not making same mistake !!! please post why .

Comment: I have managed to solve the issue by using a function instead of a procedure.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but you might edit your response and explain what you meant by 'instead'.  Instead of...what?